# All Test Methods Failing at Constructors [Homework]

Tags: java, junit, computer-science

I have a super class and several subclasses. For some reason, when I run my JUnit tests all of my methods are failing where I try to construct the subclass and when I try to debug it I'm getting this error message that says

> Source not found: The JAR of this class file belongs to JUnit 4 which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries.

Here's my super class

```
public class Sequence {

protected char[] seqarr;

public boolean isValidLetter(char let){
    boolean isValid = false;
    if (Character.isUpperCase(let) == true || Character.isLowerCase(let) == true){
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}


public Sequence(char[] sarr){

    boolean check = true;
    for (int i = 0; i<sarr.length; i++){
        if (isValidLetter(sarr[i]) == false){
        check = false;
        break;
        }
    }
    if (check == true){
        seqarr = sarr;
    }

    if (check == false){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sequence letter for class edu.iastate.cs228.hw1.Sequence"); //Need to figure out how to make this say whatever class it came from

    }



}

public int seqLength(){
    return seqarr.length;

}

public char[] getSeq(){
    char[] seqCopy = seqarr;
    return seqCopy;

}

public String toString(){
    String stringSeq = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < seqarr.length; i++){
        stringSeq = stringSeq + seqarr[i];
    }
    return stringSeq;

}

public boolean equals(Object obj){
    boolean check = false;
    if (obj != null && (seqarr.toString().toLowerCase() == obj.toString().toLowerCase())){
        check = true;
    }
    return check;

}





}
```

Here's one of my subclasses

```
public class DNASequence extends Sequence {


@Override
public boolean isValidLetter(char let){
    return "aAcCgGtT".indexOf(let) != -1;
}


public DNASequence(char[] dnaarr){
    super(dnaarr);
}
}
```

And here's that subclass's test case
    public class DNASequenceTest {

```
char[] testArrOne = {'a','B','c','D'};

@Test
public void testValidLetter() {
    String msg = "Method should return true if the character is a/A, c/C, g/G, or t/T";
    DNASequence newDNASequence = new DNASequence(testArrOne);
    assertEquals(msg, true, newDNASequence.isValidLetter('a'));

    }


@Test
public void testValidLetterTwo(){
    DNASequence newDNASequence = new DNASequence(testArrOne);
    assertEquals(false, newDNASequence.isValidLetter('P'));
}



@Test
public void testConstructor(){
    String msg = "The constructor should call the super and initialize seqarr to the input if all compnents are valid.";
    DNASequence newDNASequence = new DNASequence(testArrOne);
    Sequence newSequence = new Sequence(testArrOne);
    assertArrayEquals(msg, testArrOne, newDNASequence.getSeq());
    assertArrayEquals(msg, testArrOne, newSequence.getSeq());
}
}
```

Edit: My Failure List
DNASequenceTest
hw1.DNASequenceTest
testValidLetterTwo(hw1.DNASequenceTest)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid sequence letter for class edu.iastate.cs228.hw1.Sequence

```
at hw1.Sequence.<init>(Sequence.java:35)

at hw1.DNASequence.<init>(DNASequence.java:13)

at hw1.DNASequenceTest.testValidLetterTwo(DNASequenceTest.java:22)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)

at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)

at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

testValidLetter(hw1.DNASequenceTest)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid sequence letter for class edu.iastate.cs228.hw1.Sequence

```
at hw1.Sequence.<init>(Sequence.java:35)

at hw1.DNASequence.<init>(DNASequence.java:13)

at hw1.DNASequenceTest.testValidLetter(DNASequenceTest.java:14)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)

at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)

at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

testConstructor(hw1.DNASequenceTest)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid sequence letter for class edu.iastate.cs228.hw1.Sequence

```
at hw1.Sequence.<init>(Sequence.java:35)

at hw1.DNASequence.<init>(DNASequence.java:13)

at hw1.DNASequenceTest.testConstructor(DNASequenceTest.java:31)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)

at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)

at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: what is the error in failing?

Comment: Please show the **exact** error

Comment: *when I try to debug it I'm getting this error message that says

Source not found: The JAR of this class file belongs to JUnit 4 which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries.* - This is a red herring.  It will happen when you try to step into code that that you do not have the source code for

Comment: Hello, I tried copying the failure trace but it says it's too long to comment (my life) is there another way to find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you always use `testArrOne` as an argument to `DNASequence`'s constructor, which checks for each element if the letter is valid. But `B` and `D` are *not* valid, so the test always fails with an `IllegalArgumentException`.

You could make a test array that only contains valid input as to use as an argument:

```
char[] testArrValid = { 'a', 'G', 'c', 'T' };
```

...

```
@Test
public void testValidLetter() {
    String msg = "Method should return true if the character is a/A, c/C, g/G, or t/T";
    DNASequence newDNASequence = new DNASequence(testArrValid); // <-- use here
    assertEquals(msg, true, newDNASequence.isValidLetter('a'));
}
```

Comment: and how does it work without clarifying the runner class?

Comment: @KamyarParastesh Eclipse takes care of that for me, I can just use "run as junit test". And I know the error because I ran the code.

Answer (score -1):

A possible reason is, you have not added the proper classes to run your junit tests

```
@RunWith(springjunit4classrunner.class)
 class DNASequenceTest {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It says runwith cannot be resolved to a type and I'm getting a box popping up saying "Obsolete Methods on Stack"